# Active buttons and a never-disappearing `MediaController` at the same time, possible?

Tags: android, layout, media-player, mediacontroller

I implemented a simple MediaController using this code (which I found here on stackoverflow). My first problem is that I want the `MediaController` to be visible always. I can override the `hide()` method, but at this point I cannot exit from my app with the BACK button. I read that overriding `dispatchKeyEvent()` might solve the problem, but it has no effect for me.

Actually my second question is how to make active buttons when using this? Not new buttons in the media player, but I want them in another layout (I will have about 15 different buttons). If I make a new `LinearLayout` in my xml, that layout with the buttons is NOT active until the mediacontroller is on the screen. The touchEvent makes the `MediaController` disappear and THEN I can press the buttons. Is it possible to have active buttons and a never-disappearing `MedaiController` on the screen at the same time?

```
public class PlayAudioActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl {
    private static final String PLAY_AUDIO = "PLAY_AUDIO";
    private MediaController mMediaController;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context=this;

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this)
          /* {
                  @Override
                public void hide()
                {
                  mMediaController.show(0);
                }
            }*/; 

        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(PlayAudioActivity.this);
        mMediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.audioView));



       // String audioFile = "" ; 
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.audioplayer/raw/song"));
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(PLAY_AUDIO, "Could not open file " + "  " + " for playback.", e);
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mMediaController.show(0);
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        int percentage = (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mMediaPlayer.getDuration();

        return percentage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }


    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    /*public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)

        finish();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mMediaController.show(0);

        return false;
    }
}
```

My xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/audioView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/audioView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```